# Implement a simple NN using Tensorflow, want values as outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am following the link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners

But in my case, I do not want one-hot vectors as the results ([True, False, True,..]). I want numeric values as outputs. 
So I want to write my own evaluation parts, to measure the accuracy. For example, I will have maybe a vector of values ([1,2,3,....]) as an output. I am thinking maybe cosine similarity could be a good way. Then I will normalise the similarity to range of [0,1]. (That's where I am)
Could anyone give better ideas on how I can measure the accuracy?

Comment: If you want predicted probabilities, that's in `y`. IE, `y[i,j]` gives confidence of `i`-observation having label `j`

Comment: I've fixed that, by eliminating the softmax function :)